# Tell javac to read class/interface dependency from classfile

Tags: java, class, terminal, javac

I'm experimenting with java to see if I can build a plugin system into my application.
The one rule I want the plugins to adhere to is that they need to implement interface `Cake`.
My directory is:

```
Projectfolder
   bin
      Foo.class
      Cake.class
   src
      Foo.java
      Bar.java
      Cake.java
```

`Cake.java` and `Foo.java` is in package `test.package` and `Bar.java` is in lets say `plugin.stuff` package (since I don't control this it could of course be anything).
`Foo.java` and `Cake.java` compiles to JBC (JavaByteCode) without a problem.

Since I don't want to ship my application code to everyone interested in creating a plugin I want to read the information about the interface `Cake` (which is implemented in `Bar.java`) from it's .class file. Is this possible?
What javac commands is needed to tell javac to take dependency `Cake` from `Cake.class`?

To clarify I want to be able to go from:

```
Foo.class
Cake.class
Bar.java
```

to:

```
Foo.class
Cake.class
Bar.class
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do here. You've said that the plugins have to implement `Cake`. For them to do that, they have to have the `Cake` interface (`Cake.class`, typically wrapped up in a jar) at a minimum. Regardless, *your* code doesn't have to explicitly load `Cake` from a class file dynamically (the classloader used to run the program -- such as the one built into the `java` tool -- will do that). Why do you think it needs to?

Comment: Do I HAVE to wrap a .class file in a jar to be able to use it to compile a .java class using a class or interface from that class file? Is it not possible to just supply the .class file directly?

Comment: No, you don't have to wrap it in a jar, that's why I said "typically." The `.class` file is all that's needed.

Comment: As long as Java class can be found on [CLASSPATH](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html) it will be used.

Comment: Upon running "javac Bar.java" i get error 
"Bar.java:3: error <identifier> expected
import ./test.package.DisplayPlugin;"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I found the error or at least I got it working.
Since the file `Foo.class` and `Cake.class` wasn't placed in folder `src/test/package/` the classes/interfaces was not found.

When I created this hierarchy:

```
Projectfolder
   bin
      test
         package
            Foo.class
            Cake.class
   src
      Bar.java
```

and in the bin folder ran the command `javac ..\src\Bar.java` then the command ran fine and `Bar.class` file was generated in the `src` folder next to the `Bar.java` file.